# How do I detect if players have sufficient EXP levels?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make an XP shop but I'm not sure about how to detect if people have sufficient XP Levels.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test for player's levels using the `l=` or `lm=` arguments in the target selector.

For example, if I am looking for all players with at 5 or more levels, I would use:

```
/testfor @a[lm=5]
```

or, all players that have 3 or more levels of EXP, but equal to/less than 8:

```
/testfor @a[l=8,lm=3]
```

or, all players that have 5 or less levels:

```
/testfor @a[l=5]
```

or, exactly 8 levels:

```
/testfor @a[l=8,lm=8]
```

*as 8 will be true for both `lm` and `l` but 7 will become false for `lm` and 9 would be false for `l` because a selector will only select players IF all the arguments are true.*

See [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) for more information.

Comment: So would I do /testfor @a[l=8,lm=8] if I wanted players to have to have exactly 8 levels?

Comment: That's correct. 8 will be true for both `lm` and `l` but 7 will become false for `lm` and 9 would be false for `l`. Remember: **A selector will only select players IF all the arguments are true.**