# Minecraft; How can you use command blocks to detect player levels?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to work on redstone works with a new adventure map, how can I make command blocks detect player levels? That's my main question, the rest I know how to work out but here's the purpose anyway, I'm trying to make a command block detect player levels and at a certain amount of levels an action will happen (yet to be decided) but I know how to do that, just use a comparator to link up to the next command block and continue out the line of commands needed.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191912/how-do-i-detect-if-players-have-sufficient-exp-levels) may help you.

Basically, you just need two tags : `l=` and `lm=`

`l=`is the maximum level, while `lm=`is the minimum level.

So if you want to detect people with 5 levels, do:

`/testfor @a[l=5,lm=5]`

**Source: [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191912/how-do-i-detect-if-players-have-sufficient-exp-levels) question by (answer)aytimothy and FireStrike289**